# How can I improve my Visual Studio 2012 Typescript Workflow?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, typescript

I am an Actionscript Developer who is new to TypeScript and Visual Studio.  My biggest problems right now are related to workflow.

Visual Studio 12 is a feature rich environment, as an Eclipse user it feels familiar but I feel it is heavy and bloated for my needs. I feel like 80% of the features are not required from a TypeScript perspective? Is there anything I can do to improve the software?

When I press the debug button on a TypeScript program, I run Chrome, but this process takes about 16 seconds to launch, is this normal and again can this be improved?

Finally, maybe it is just the case that Visual Studio is above me and this whole question is stupid, but in this case, is there any other IDEs that are good right now for TypeScript development and pretty much simple to setup and use?

Comment: I am still open to relevant answers, but I found this http://jessefreeman.com/dev-techniques/automating-typescript-with-node-and-grunt/ and it seems to solve the slow building thing.

Comment: Why you close chrome?Make changes - Build - Refresh page on chrome - Debug. This of course, about javascript debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebStorm from JetBrains features TypeScript editing, is lighter-weight than VS, and might be better for your needs: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#IDE_and_editor_support)'s a list of others:

> Microsoft provides a plug-in for Visual Studio 2012 and WebMatrix as
>   well as basic text editor support for Sublime Text, Emacs and Vim.
>   JetBrains supports TypeScript with code completion, refactoring and
>   debugging in its web application IDE's PhpStorm 6 and WebStorm 6.
>   The online Cloud9 IDE also supports TypeScript.

If you continue with VS2012 then the [WebEssentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) extension is very useful.

In terms of performance, you shouldn't need to launch the debugger every time you make changes. Setting [compile-on-save](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save) means you should be able to make changes, then simply refresh the page in your browser.

My typical workflow in VS2012 is Debug > Start Without Debugging (just once, at the start of a TS editing session), make changes to the TS and save them (automatically generating JS), then simply F5 the browser to see the changes. Having the [source map](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1.aspx) option on in compilation and opening the F12 tools in Chrome makes [setting breakpoints and performing other debugging tasks](http://www.aaron-powell.com/web/typescript-source-maps) straightforward.

I'm also a reformed AS developer, and I find this workflow much faster than even a good AS tool such as FlashDevelop, and miles away from developing in FlexBuilder. Do bear in mind also that TypeScript is in Alpha, and you may occasionally hit performance issues, especially on larger projects, related to this being early preview code.

Comment: People on my team have had issues with Visual Studio locking up or slowing down that were resolved when Web Essentials was uninstalled.  I've stopped recommending it.

Comment: Useful to know Jeffery, thanks. I had some issues with earlier combinations but with the current stable troika (VS 2012 Update 2 + TS 0.8.3.1 + WE 2.7) I'm not seeing frequent problems, even on quite a large (50+ modules) project.

Comment: Out of everyone with that exact same combination some ran into a problem but I personally never did.  Maybe some config file gets into a bad state?

Comment: I love web essentials but had to go off it since I went with 0.9.0 to check out generics :( +1 still.